# R - how to aggregate by group values listed in this way

Tags: r, aggregate

Given DF, how do I aggregate it to list the number of rows with successive matching Type?

For example, I would like to generate out1 or out2 from DF.

```
DF <- data.frame("Ages"=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8),"Type"=c("R","N","N","N","R","R","N","R"))
DF
  Ages Type
1    1    R
2    2    N
3    3    N
4    4    N
5    5    R
6    6    R
7    7    N
8    8    R
out1 <- data.frame("Counts"=c(1,3,2,1,1))
out1
  Counts
1      1
2      3
3      2
4      1
5      1
out2 <- data.frame("Ages"=c(1,4,6,7,8),"Counts"=c(1,3,2,1,1))
out2
  Ages Counts
1    1      1
2    4      3
3    6      2
4    7      1
5    8      1
```

Comment: please leave out the prompts

Comment: Do you mean `with(DF, rle(levels(Type)[Type])$lengths)`?